# How can I make Jenkins deploy my project to JBoss EAP(AS7)

Tags: java, maven, jboss, jenkins, jboss7.x

How can I make Jenkins deploy my project to JBoss EAP(AS7)?

I see that Jenkins can deploy a project to JBoss 5.x if it builds ok but how can I make it deploy to AS7 or EAP if it builds ok?  Can someone please tell me if this can be done.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the official [JBoss Application Server Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as-maven-plugin).

Attach it to the `install` phase and configure Jenkins to execute `mvn clean install`. If you don't feel comfortable attaching the execution, you can call it directly: 
 `mvn jboss-as:deploy`

Here is an example of a build setup:

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
        <configuration>
            <hostname>${deploy.jboss.host}</hostname>
            <port>${deploy.jboss.port}</port>
            <username>${deploy.jboss.user}</username>
            <password>${deploy.jboss.password}</password>
            <name>${backend.deployment-name}</name>
            <filename>${project.build.finalName}.war</filename>
            <skip>${skipDeployment}</skip>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>deploy-jar</id>
                <phase>install</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>deploy</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

**EDIT** Jenkins config - after you create a maven project, there is a setting for what goals to execute. Search for the **Build** config, and there, for the input labeled **goals and options** - enter the goals into this input.

Configuring the Jboss AS plugin - see the `<configuration>` part in the **pom** snippet above - you can set the `<hostname>` to 127.0.0.1 to test locally.

Comment: this looks good but how do I tell Jenkins to run a mvn install

Comment: also if I do this jboss-as:deploy does not go to my local AS7 server for testing anymore.. Both commands will goto the remote server

Comment: @techsjs2012 - have added some more config details, hope it helps - see my edit. Also please see the official jenkins and joboss-as plugin docs. They are good :)

Comment: Kostha this is over my head, can you please help

Comment: @techsjs2012 - I am not sure about th issue - It might be too much for the comments. I have created a chatroom named q14381345. Perhaps we can sort things out.

Comment: @techsjs2012 - go to the chat option on the top menu bar, on the right side of your name, search for q14381345 and join

Answer (score 0):

How do you currently deploy your application to jboss?  If you're using a script, you could have jenkins call the script.

Comment: we been doing it by hand :(

Comment: What do you mean by hand?  Like through the web console?  Or via the command line?  If it's via the command line just put those commands in a script.  Otherwise, your first step isn't with jenkins, it's getting your deploy to complete from the command line so that you can call it from jenkins.